# MSBuild - Copy one file or another depending on the Build Configuration

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a file inside my solution that is currently copied to the build output on this path: **Core\Bootstrap.txt**

(My application uses it when it runs, but I would like it to have different contents depending on the Build Configuration)

I suspect this is done modifying the csproj and playing with MSBuild, but I don't have any clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only function is that you should create wo other txt files called `Bootstrap.Debug.txt` and `Bootstrap.Release.txt`.

**First**, set **Copy to Output Directory** of these two other files to `No not copy`.

**And** remember to clear `Bootstrap.txt` and then make your all content into `Bootstrap.Debug.txt` or `Bootstrap.Release.txt`. If you want to use **Debug** mode, make changes on the `Bootstrap.Debug.txt` while make changes on the `Bootstrap.Release.txt` under **Release** mode.

**Second**, unload your project, add this in the `csproj` file:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Core\Bootstrap.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Core\Bootstrap.Debug.txt">
      <DependentUpon>Bootstrap.txt</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Core\Bootstrap.Release.txt">
      <DependentUpon>Bootstrap.txt</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyFiles" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <Exec Command="xcopy /y $(ProjectDir)Core\Bootstrap.$(Configuration).txt $(ProjectDir)Core\Bootstrap.txt" />
  </Target>
```

[image]

**Then**, change your build configuration, then build your project. After that, you can check the `Bootstrap.txt` under the output folder, and it already contains the related content based on your configuration.

**Update**

If you did not want to use copy task, then you can directly copy the related Bootstrap.Debug or Release.txt into the output folder. And then you can directly use `Bootstrap.Debug.txt` or `Bootstrap.Release.txt` based on the configuration. That is an easier way.

Not sure whether you need the fixed name file `Bootstrap.txt`, if you do not need that, you can directly use  `Bootstrap.Debug.txt` or `Bootstrap.Release.txt`.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Core\Bootstrap.txt">
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Core\Bootstrap.Debug.txt" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
      <DependentUpon>Bootstrap.txt</DependentUpon>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Core\Bootstrap.Release.txt" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
      <DependentUpon>Bootstrap.txt</DependentUpon>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

**If** you still want the fixed name file  `Bootstrap.txt`, you have to use Copy task to make the related txt file overwrite the main `Bootstrap.txt` file. And MSBuild is not flexible enough to write some info based on the
configuration condition on the txt file and then it will add corresponding information to the corresponding build file according to the build configuration.

**MSBuild** does not have such a function, so you can only write logic manually, and overwrite the main file according to different configuration-based files.

If you do not want `xcopy` command, you can use the [msbuild copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2019), and it belongs to MSBuild.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Core\Bootstrap.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Core\Bootstrap.Debug.txt" >
      <DependentUpon>Bootstrap.txt</DependentUpon>

    </Content>
    <Content Include="Core\Bootstrap.Release.txt">
      <DependentUpon>Bootstrap.txt</DependentUpon>  
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyFiles" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
      <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)Core\Bootstrap.$(Configuration).txt" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)Core\Bootstrap.txt"></Copy>
  </Target>
```

Otherwise, there is no other way.

Comment: Thanks! Although the xcopy part looks quite tricky. Relies entirely on xcopy that isn't part of the build process. Isn't there a cleaner way to do the actual copy?

Comment: Or you should use a condition to directly copy the related Bootstrap.Debug or Release.txt into the output folder. And then you can directly use `Bootstrap.Debug.txt` or `Bootstrap.Release.txt` based on the configuration. That is an easier way. If you must explicitly use the file named Bootstrap.txt in the output file at the end, then you have to copy it to the main file. Otherwise, there is no other way. I have updated my answer and you can check it.

Comment: I'm using the solution you've proposed in the last part (without xcopy). I've noticed that Bootstrap.txt is overwritten each time I rebuild the solution. If I write inside the word "Placeholder", it gets rewritten with the one corresponding to the current configuration. I don't know why this happens!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Instead, try to use `<Exec Command="xcopy /d $(ProjectDir)Core\Bootstrap.$(Configuration).txt $(ProjectDir)Core\Bootstrap.txt ">` under `CopyFiles` target. You have to use `xcopy` task because it will skip existing files while copy task will always overwrite the existing files.

Comment: Thanks to you, Perry. I wanted to avoid the execution of OS commands directly, but it seems there's no better way than that. Right?

Comment: Yes. Copy task of msbuild is not good enough to do everything. But `xcopy` with `/d` of OS can realize this and will skip existing files. So far, you have to use OS command. Sorry to tell you this.

Answer (score 0):

A ton of the time I see people do this I see them have a separate file named Bootstrap.Development.txt and when you load the file you can check the Environment type in dotnet and load $"Bootstrap.{envName}.json" and just always load Bootstrap.json but don't use it if your envName is 'Development'

edit:
just remember in the properties for both files to always copy to output dir if newer

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is something that has to be part of the build process. Morever, I don't know you mean by "Environment"